# Streamlining uploading project folder to server using SSH + command line

Tags: command-line, bash, ssh, scp

I'm in the process of attempting to streamline my workflow. A huge part of it is uploading files quickly using SSH, but with some logic behind it. For instance, a lot of my project files are not for "live usage." For instance, I have a file for SASS (CSS compiler) that outputs to a single CSS file. When I upload my folder, I don't want to include the SASS folder (or a number of other folders/files).

Is there a way to create a command that incorporates this sort of logic, using the mac terminal, while uploading the files to my server using SSH?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you can use SSH keys passwordless authentication. In that case, you can create script, which would use SSH (SCP) for the upload of selected dirs/files only.

There is small example:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /my/dir
# following copies specified dir recursively
scp -r ./thisdir user@servername:/final/path/
# following copies only the specified file
scp ./otherdir/myfile user@servername:/final/path/otherdir/
```